# Jquery addClass doesn't seem to work in angularjs controller initialiser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<div data-ng-controller="CountdownCtrl" class="row countdown">
    <div ng-repeat="event in events" class="hidden event col-sm-4">
    ...
```

In the controller for this, I'm trying to remove the hidden class on the event DIV:

```
app.controller('CountdownCtrl', function($scope) {
    ...
    $(".countdown .event").removeClass("hidden").addClass("Hello");
    ...
```

I've tried the JQuery bit outside of the controller as well, but It just doesn't seem to fire, I've tried adding in logging as well:

```
    $(".countdown .event").removeClass(function() { $log("Hello World"); return "hidden";}).addClass("Hello");
```

The Jquery pages and examples don't seem to indicate that I need any kind of iterator.

I even tried something close to their example:

```
    $("p").removeClass(function() { $log("Hello World"); return "hidden";}).addClass("Hello");
```

but I go no logging and no paragraphs with the "Hello" class applied.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try triggering this in a button click, or with a timer? Maybe by the time the code run, there are no elements yet.

Comment: Bloody timers. My JS file is last in the ordering, so the fact it's getting into the controller would indicate that the DOM has loaded, the JQuery and Bootstrapper JS files are in and all is working... but doing a `$interval(showem, 0)` in the controller does work. Add it as an answer and I'll accept that.

Comment: Well, it's a non elegant hack, will try to dig a bit into it before posting answer to try and find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead do this in `directive` definition link function:

```
 app.directive('event', function (){
      return {
         restrict: 'C', // C for class directives
         link: function (scope, el, attrs){
              // do that here
               $(el).removeClass("hidden").addClass("Hello");
         }
     }
 });
```

Or another option is to use `ng-class` such as :

```
   <div ng-repeat="event in events" class="event col-sm-4" ng-class='{hidden: 2+2==4}'>
```

Here you can notice it should have some truthy condition to be added else it shouldn't.

Comment: Initlally all the elements are hidden. Once I have updated the content, I want to show them all. I need to do this as I don't know how many timers I have at the point of HTML writing (it's in the javascript code), so the "Hello" will be replaced with the col-sm-(12/n)

Answer (score 0):

Is this working? You have forgotten an `,`

```
$(".countdown,.event").removeClass("hidden").addClass("Hello");
```

> $(".intro,.demo")         All elements with the class "intro"
>   or "demo"

see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: Yep, it works, I want the .event divs inside the .countdown containing divs.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
app.controller('CountdownCtrl', function($scope) {
  // default eventClass value
  $scope.eventClass = 'hidden';

  ...
  // your logic
  $scope.eventClass = 'Hello';
  ...
```

Html:

```
<div data-ng-controller="CountdownCtrl" class="row countdown">
    <div ng-repeat="event in events" class="{{eventClass}} event col-sm-4">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wait until all elements are loaded.

One way is wrapping it with `$(document).ready()` outside the controller code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".countdown .event").removeClass("hidden").addClass("Hello");
});
```

However, keep in mind that if you change the state without full page reload, the code won't run again. In such a case, you need to handle the state change event and add the code there as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try This,

```
  $(".countdown, .event").removeClass("hidden").addClass("Hello");
```

Comment: Nope, I want the .event divs inside the .countdown containing divs, not all of them, and anything else that may be classed event.